# Access denied to a folder my user owns?

Tags: permissions

I'm the owner of a folder, yet I cannot cd into the folder.

After some searching I discovered that you need execute permission to cd into the folder.

I then did:

```
sudo chmod u+w myfolder
```

To add execute permission for my user. Yet I still cannot open the folder.

Comment: What folder is it? Where is it located? It would be a huge help if you included the results of `ls -lh folderName` in the directory of your folder (replacing `yourFolder` with the actual folder name)

Comment: /var/www/my-site result of sudo ls -lh: drw-r--r-- 13 myuser www-data 4.0K Oct 21 15:51 site

Comment: and where does that show -execute- permissions? `drw-` = directory, read, write, no execute. `sudo chmod 755 myfolder` is the command to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command you entered

```
sudo chmod u+w myfolder
```

grants **w**rite permission to the owner... There it is:

```
drw-r--r-- 13 myuser www-data
  ^--owner may write
```

You wanted e**x**ecute permission

```
chmod u+x myfolder
```

(you won't need `sudo` if you own it). That will give you

```
drwxr--r-- 13 myuser www-data
   ^--owner may enter and search
```

(octal `744`) - but there's not much point in that setting - probably you either want `755` (all can access) or `750` (owner and group can access) or `700` (only owner can access), since read permission for directories isn't much use without execute permission.